# Unexpected behavior of FindGeneratingFunction

Tags: symbolic, integer-sequence

`FindGeneratingFunction` will give up to computer sometimes?Such as

```
FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, x]
```

But actually the $1 + 4 x + 6 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4$ is expected.As the same `GeneratingFunction` will give up to compute.

```
GeneratingFunction[Binomial[4, n - 1], n, x, Assumptions -> 1 < n < 4]
```

Or I have a misunderstand this two function?

Comment: Compare `FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, x]` and `FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, x]` with yours.  Also, it appears that by definition `n` runs from `0` to `Infinity`, so perhaps your use of `Assumptions` is ignored.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Wow,you have done it.And do you mean the `GeneratingFunction` is unsuitable here?Another suggestion that I think you should post the comment as answer.I will accept that,I think it can help some friends.The documentation have no this aspect specifcation after all.

Comment: You may also specify the function space you want `FindGeneratingFunction` to explore: `FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, x, FunctionSpace -> "Polynomial"]` returns the polynomial you expected.

Comment: @MarcoB Wow~Magic!!Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "help" `FindGeneratingFunction` by specifying the function space you want it to explore:

```
FindGeneratingFunction[{1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, x, FunctionSpace -> "Polynomial"]
```

This returns the $1 + 4 x + 6 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4$ polynomial you expected.